# Finding the first non NA value after a certain value by groups

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I'm dealing with some time series data `df` and trying to adding a position index to the first non-NA values after a certain number, in my case `5`.

Here are the sample data.

```
Group Year Value 
1     2001  4
1     2002  9
1     2003  5
1     2004  NA
1     2005  NA
2     2001  22
2     2002  10
2     2003  5
2     2004  NA
2     2005  3
3     2001  NA
3     2002  NA
3     2003  5
3     2004  7
3     2005  NA
```

So the expected results should be as follows:

```
Group Year Value Index
1     2001  4     NA
1     2002  9     NA
1     2003  5     0
1     2004  NA    NA
1     2005  NA    NA
2     2001  22    NA
2     2002  10    NA
2     2003  5     5
2     2004  NA    NA
2     2005  3     NA
3     2001  NA    NA
3     2002  NA    NA
3     2003  5     4
3     2004  7     NA
3     2005  NA    NA
```

I tried the following code but couldn't get the desired results:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(Index = case_when(Value ==5 & 
(is.na(lead(Value, default = Value[5])) | 
is.na(lead(Value, n=2, default = Value[5])) | 
is.na(lead(Value, n=3, default = Value[5])) | 
is.na(lead(Value, n=4, default = Value[5])))) ~ 1, True ~ 0)
```

Sorry for the naive code, and would you please give some suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you number from 0

Comment: Not clear...also how do you get the values `0, 5, 4`?

Comment: @Sotos Thanks. They are just the position of the first non-NA values. For the Group 1, every value after 5 is NA, so the position index was set 0. And for the Group 2, first non-NA value after 5 is 3 which is the fifth of the group, so the position index is 5. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Why in group 3 values for 2004 and 2005 swap?

Comment: @akrun Many thanks. In Group 1, there was no 'non-NA' values after `5`, so I assigned the position index to 0.

Comment: @M-- Thank you. It's a mistake..I've revised it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo = function(x, v = 5) {
    ind_v = which(x == v)[1]
    x[seq_along(x) <= ind_v] = NA
    ind_non_na = which(!is.na(x))[1]
    x[seq_along(x) > ind_non_na] = NA
    x[max(ind_non_na, ind_v, na.rm = TRUE)] = max(0, ind_non_na, na.rm = TRUE)
    return(x)
}

library(dplyr)
d %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    mutate(Index = foo(Value))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
   mutate(ind = cumsum(Value %in% 5),
          rn = row_number()) %>%
   group_by(ind, add = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(Index =  rn[ind==1][!is.na(Value[ind == 1])][2], 
      Index2= match(Value, 5),
       Index2 = case_when(!is.na(Index2)~ Index, TRUE ~ NA_integer_)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-ind, -rn, -Index)
```